# list of task assignees in APEX

Tags: soql, tasks

How can I query the list of task assignees with SOQL?
I need to find out all the users to whom a task is assigned in APEX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you taken a look at the [TaskRelation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_taskrelation.htm) object? If you provide the TaskId you can retrieve all the RelationIds, which you'd then need to query to convert to Contacts/Users/etc.

```
SELECT Name FROM User WHERE Id IN (SELECT RelationId FROM TaskRelation WHERE TaskId = 'xxx')
```